# How to get the app name which is running on foreground in android?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, foreground-service

I want to know the app name or package name which is running in the foreground (which is currently visible on the screen). Could someone tell me is it possible? I came to know that the functions like `getRunningTasks()`, `getRunningAppProcess()` are removed from android.
I just want to know the app/package name. Can somebody please help me?

Comment: do you want to see which app is running in android studio, or through an android app of your own ? those are different things, your question title is a bit confusing

Comment: I want to know through my android app. Actually I am building a keyboard app so I want to know which app is using keyboard at some point of time. Sorry if the question is confusing, I wanted to mention that I build the app in android studio.

Comment: no problem , i was just checking, there's no need to include android studio in your question then, i've removed it :)

Comment: @a_local_nobody Could you please tell me is there any solution to this? Some people say try to root the app. I didn't understand whether we can get it by rooting. Could you please clarify regarding rooting if possible?

Comment: if i knew the answer, i would have written one, sorry